# How to parse the values?

Tags: java, json

I'm having a Json file like this `{"Name":"Saaa","AppIcon":"ddd.jpg","Wallpaper.jpg","ddd.jpg"]}`.  I need to extract the `AppIcon` values.I'm using `json simple` lib to parse the `json`.The code snippet to parse the values is as below.

`FileReader appIconReader = new FileReader("jsonpath.json");
JSONObject jsonIconObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(appIconReader);
System.out.println("APPLICATION ICON = "+jsonIconObject.get("AppIcon"));`

But the output what I'm gettin is a single string as below:
`["ddd.jpg","Wallpaper.jpg","ddd.jpg"]`

I need to extract the individual values like this

- ddd.jpg
- Wallpaper.jpg
- ddd.jpg

Not with the square brackets([]) and double quotes("") as I'm getting right now.How can I do that?

Comment: `["ddd.jpg","Wallpaper.jpg","ddd.jpg"]` --> looks like a `list` / `array`.

Comment: Are you getting it from JSON? Use a JSON parser. You should provide more details.

Comment: if they are the way you describe it, they already are separate String objects in an array, as TheLostMind said

Comment: What is it array list or json?

Comment: Yeah,I'm getting it from `json`. I'm using the `json simple` lib for parsing but if i extract the value I'll get it like this `["ddd.jpg","Wallpaper.jpg","ddd.jpg"]` but I need the individual values like ddd.jpg wallpaper.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you want :

```
String filePath = "pathofjson\\test.json";
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
        JSONArray lang= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("AppIcon");
        System.out.println(lang);
        for(int i=0; i<lang.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(lang.get(i));

        }


    } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @M.Sharms: `FileReader appIconReader = new FileReader("jsonpath.json");
   JSONObject jsonIconObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(appIconReader);
   System.out.println("APPLICATION ICON = "+jsonIconObject.get("AppIcon"));` I used this...but the result is like this `["ddd.jpg","Wallpaper.jpg","ddd.jpg"]`

Answer (score 4):

Try with `JSON`.

```
    String str="[\"ddd.jpg\",\"Wallpaper.jpg\",\"ddd.jpg\"]";
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<String[]>() {
    }.getType();
    String[] a=new Gson().fromJson(str,collectionType);
    for (String i:a){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Output

```
   ddd.jpg
   Wallpaper.jpg
   ddd.jpg
```

Edit:  for your edited question answer like this.

```
 public class Obj{
  private String name;
  private List<String> appIcons;

  public List<String> getAppIcons() {
     return appIcons;
  }

  public void setAppIcons(List<String> appIcons) {
     this.appIcons = appIcons;
  }

  public String getName() {
     return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Now you can simply pass your `JSON`

```
String str = "{\"name\":\"Saaa\",\"appIcons\":
                               [\"ddd.jpg\",\"Wallpaper.jpg\",\"ddd.jpg\"]}";
Obj obj = new Gson().fromJson(str, Obj.class);
System.out.println(obj.getAppIcons());
```

Output:

```
[ddd.jpg, Wallpaper.jpg, ddd.jpg]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have your source string:

```
String str = "[\"ddd.jpg\",\"Wallpaper.jpg\",\"ddd.jpg\"]";
```

Substring it:

```
str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
```

Split it:

```
String[] parts = str.split(",");
```

Substring each part:

```
for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    parts[i] = parts[i].substring(1, parts[i].length() - 1);
}
```

Now you have an array with each value. Note that this is unsafe, add checks before substringing.

Comment: This in fact answers the question _as it is_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceAll` and `split`

```
String s="[\"ddd.jpg\",\"Wallpaper.jpg\",\"ddd.jpg\"]";
String array[]=s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\"]", "").split(","));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array);
```

- `replaceAll` removes `[` `]` and `"` from `String`
- `split` gives array of `String` by splitting the `String` with use of `,`(delimeter)
- `Arrays.toString` used to print Array.

***OUTPUT***

```
[ddd.jpg, Wallpaper.jpg, ddd.jpg]
```

---

With `JSON` you can try this

```
      String s="{\"Name\":\"Saaa\","+
            " \"AppIcon\":[\"ddd.jpg\",\"Wallpaper.jpg\",\"ddd.jpg\"]}";
       org.json.JSONObject json=new org.json.JSONObject(s);
       org.json.JSONArray jarray=json.getJSONArray("AppIcon");
       System.out.println(jarray.get(0));//Will give ddd.jpg
       //Iterate over array to get all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String str = "[\"ddd.jpg\",\"Wallpaper.jpg\",\"ddd.jpg\"]";
String tempStr = str.replaceAll("\\W{2,}", ",");
String substring = tempStr.substring(1, tempStr.length() -1);
String[] strArray = substring.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `java.util.StringTokenizer`

```
String s = "[\"ddd.jpg\",\"Wallpaper.jpg\",\"ddd.jpg\"]";

StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, "[\",]");
while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(tokenizer.nextElement()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the description this is what you asked for:

```
String s = "[\"ddd.jpg\",\"Wallpaper.jpg\",\"ddd.jpg\"," +
           "\"Wallpaper.jpg\",\"ddd.jpg\"," +
           "\"Wallpaper.jpg\",\"ddd.jpg\"]";
String [] almost_the_words = s.split("\",\"");
int l = almost_the_words.length;
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
String temp1 = almost_the_words[0].split("\"")[1];
String temp2 = almost_the_words[l-1].split("\"")[0];

words.add(temp1);
for(int i=1; i< l-1; i++) {
    words.add(almost_the_words[i]);
}
words.add(temp2);

for(String w : words) {
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Parse a JSON File with those Strings using GSON:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyObject {

    ArrayList<String> appicon;

    public MyObject(ArrayList<String> appicon) {
         super();
         this.appicon = appicon;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAppicon() {
         return appicon;
    }

    public void setAppicon(ArrayList<String> appicon) {
         this.appicon = appicon;
    }


}
```

Use the class "MyObject" with the Library GSON: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: See the edited part for a solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry...I guess my question was not so clear.I edited my question..Can you please have a look at that?

Comment: If you are getting that last string you can see my first solution to parse the individual words...

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it is working fine.Is there any solution that I can directly get such values from the `json` parser.

Comment: You can use GSON to parse the JSON file with the object I putted on the "Edit" part. It's a pretty simple library, you should be able to understand it easily. Then, you would have an object "MyObject" with the ArrayList<String> with your final words.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a possible solution:

```
String data = "{\"Name\":\"Saaa\",\"AppIcon\":[\"ddd.jpg\",\"Wallpaper.jpg\",\"ddd.jpg\"]}";

data = data.replaceAll("(.*\"AppIcon\":\\[)(.+)(\\].*)", "$2");
data = data.replaceAll("\"", "");
for(String str: data.split(",")) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

which only involves the String class explicitly, and works for every String which the format defined in the question (which has "AppIcon:[]").