# Java: Parsing the JSON file

Tags: java, string, json

I have a Json file like this

```
{"Name":"Saaa","AppIcon":["ddd.jpg","Wallpaper.jpg","ddd.jpg"]}
```

I need to extract the `AppIcon` values. I'm using `json simple` lib to parse the `json`. The code snippet to parse the values is:

```
FileReader appIconReader = new FileReader("jsonpath.json");
JSONObject jsonIconObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(appIconReader);
System.out.println("APPLICATION ICON = "+jsonIconObject.get("AppIcon"));`
```

But the output what I'm getting is a single string:

```
["ddd.jpg","Wallpaper.jpg","ddd.jpg"]
```

I need to extract the individual values like this

```
ddd.jpg
Wallpaper.jpg
ddd.jpg
```

Not with the square brackets ([]) and double quotes ("") as I'm getting right now. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse the values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651923/how-to-parse-the-values)

Comment: You got answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651923/how-to-parse-the-values/24652152#24652152

Comment: So you posted the same question on two different sites.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  Please update your question with the exact JSON you're dealing with.

Comment: @HotLicks: That was a typo...I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSON.simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) isn't very thoroughly documented, but [it looks like](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) if you want to deal with an array, you need to cast the object returned by `.get()`:

```
JSONArray appIcon = (JSONArray)jsonIconObject.get("AppIcon");
```

A `JSONArray` appears to be a generic container you can iterate, e.g.:

```
Iterator<String> it = appIcon.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) System.out.println(it.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one also and it is store value in list type :

```
 try {
        FileReader appIconReader = new FileReader("jsonpath.json");
        JSONObject jsonIconObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(appIconReader);
        JSONArray lan = jsonIconObject.get("AppIcon"));
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
            list.add(lan.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
        }

    } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```